# Can one see which YouTube user created a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, privacy, youtube-channel

A YouTube user may create a YouTube channel via https://www.youtube.com/account -> `Create a channel`. Can one see which YouTube user created a YouTube channel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to see which YouTube user created a YouTube channel. I believe it's to protect their privacy.